# Como le arreglo este error a visual studio 2019

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2019

Básicamente hice un sistema de facturación pero ahora no me deja publicarlo, osea realizarle el instalador, adjunto imagen del error que me da cada que hago un intento

Estoy utilizando .NET Framework 4.5.2 como pueden ver, pero me da ese error no sé porque razón.

Si podrían ayudarme a solucionar dicho problema, serían de gran ayuda, muchas gracias

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: En la firma tenes todo?

Comment: Lo publicarás usando ClickOnce?

Comment: Pon la parte de la firma